# Root доступ в debian

Tags: debian

Здравствуйте, как можно получить доступ к всем папкам и файлам с возможностью изменения в них информации, стоит у меня debian.

Comment: Лучше sudo чем su...

Comment: хм... странный вопрос.

Comment: @pyatak, постарайтесь писать более развернуть ответы.

Comment: Руководствовался справкой и мин.кол-вом символов в ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root` живет только в терминале, получить права рута можно командой `su` и введя пароль или запустив рутовый терминал.

но, как правильно было подмечено, неправославно работать под `root`, запускать команды, которые требуют привелигированного пользователя, лучше через `sudo`

подробнее это можно почиать на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/44783/)

Comment: Вы не совсем правы, повышение привилегий можно получить не в терминале с помощью [gksu][1]  [1]: http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=gksu&category=1&russian=2

Comment: "root живет только в терминале"Не правда ваша. Делаем кнопочку "sudo nautilus /" и радуемся в иксах.Делаем кнопочку "sudo gedit" и получаем сразу редактор с правами рута.

Comment: а тот пароль, что потребует sudo куда вводить? не у всех же судо без пароля пускает.. не секурно же это

Comment: Дружище, а куда ты вводишь пароль, когда делаешь обновление системы? Оно т оже без sudo не пашет.Система выдаст соответствующее окошко

Answer (score 1):

Погодите. Человек просит права на редактирование файлов и папок, а не на запуск кода. ИМХО тут надо копать в сторону chroot (в качестве аргумента указываем полный путь до места, где смонтирован нужный нам раздел)

Comment: Хотя чествую, товарисчи меня сейчас заклюют :)

Comment: Ага. Если в утилите встречается слово "root", еще не значит что она что то там от суперпользователя)

Answer (score -1):

Никто не мешает запустить nautilus от root-а и делать, что заблагорассудится. Есть пакет, позволяющий это делать:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-gksu gksu nautilus
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что в вопросе речь идёт о nautilus?

Comment: почему вы решили, что я решил. я предположил, т.к. в изначальной версии был указан Debian Gnome и не было указанно, как он хочет получить доступ к данным через консоль или GUI, про консоль сказали, я добавил GUI

Comment: Вопрос имеет одну версию и в нем о GUI ни слова.  Впрочем вопрос очень низкого качества и на него не стоило вообще отвечать.